# Associative array Add new values

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

```
    Array
    (
        [RX Housing] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [reg_id] => 63
                        [vRegionName] => Boston
                        [Forwarded] => 1
                        [Accepted] => 0
                        [Rejected] => 0
                        [Dupe] => 0
                        [PotentialLease] => 0
                        [Lcpc] => 0
                        [CloseLead] => 0
                         [TotalInvamt] => 0.00
                    )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reg_id] => 41
                    [vRegionName] => Chicago
                    [Forwarded] => 1
                    [Accepted] => 0
                    [Rejected] => 0
                    [Dupe] => 0
                    [PotentialLease] => 0
                    [Lcpc] => 0
                    [CloseLead] => 1
                    [TotalInvamt] => 954.00
                )
       )
)


Array
(
    [RX Housing] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reg_id] => 63
                    [TotalInv] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reg_id] => 41
                    [TotalInv] => 8
                )

        )

)
```

i want to add [TotalInv] on First array based on [reg_id] , how can i do this?? pls help me.

i want this output::

```
Array
(
    [RX Housing] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reg_id] => 63
                    [vRegionName] => Boston
                    [Forwarded] => 1
                    [Accepted] => 0
                    [Rejected] => 0
                    [Dupe] => 0
                    [PotentialLease] => 0
                    [Lcpc] => 0
                    [CloseLead] => 0
                    [TotalInvamt] => 0.00
                    [TotalInv] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reg_id] => 41
                    [vRegionName] => Chicago
                    [Forwarded] => 1
                    [Accepted] => 0
                    [Rejected] => 0
                    [Dupe] => 0
                    [PotentialLease] => 0
                    [Lcpc] => 0
                    [CloseLead] => 1
                    [TotalInvamt] => 954.00
                    [TotalInv] => 8
                )
       )
)
```

Thank in advance.
Vims Mak

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend when defining your first array to set the keys to the reg_id.

For example if you were creating this array from query results:

```
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($blah)){
    $id = $row['reg_id'];
    $results[$id] = $row;
}
```

Then when you loop through your second array you can easily update the first.

```
foreach($secondArray as $key => $row){
    $id = $row['reg_id'];
    $val = $row['TotalInv'];
    $first[$id]['TotalInv'] = $val;
}
```

Arrays are a beautiful thing! Hope that helps!

-fie

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
foreach($yourArr["RX Housing"] as $key => $val) {
  if($val["reg_id"] == 10) {
    $yourArr["RX Housing"][$key]["TotalInv"] = 2;
  }
  else {
    $yourArr["RX Housing"][$key]["TotalInv"] = 20;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $a = Array
    (
    'RX Housing' => Array
        (
        Array
            (
            'reg_id' => 63,
            'vRegionName' => 'Boston',
            'Forwarded' => 1,
            'Accepted' => 0,
            'Rejected' => 0,
            'Dupe' => 0,
            'PotentialLease' => 0,
            'Lcpc' => 0,
            'CloseLead' => 0,
            'TotalInvamt' => 0.00
        ),
        Array
            (
            'reg_id' => 41,
            'vRegionName' => 'Chicago',
            'Forwarded' => 1,
            'Accepted' => 0,
            'Rejected' => 0,
            'Dupe' => 0,
            'PotentialLease' => 0,
            'Lcpc' => 0,
            'CloseLead' => 1,
            'TotalInvamt' => 954.00
        )
    )
);


$b = Array
    (
    'RX Housing' => Array
        (
        Array
            (
            'reg_id' => 63,
            'TotalInv' => 2
        ),
        Array
            (
            'reg_id' => 41,
            'TotalInv' => 8
        )
    )
);

foreach ($a['RX Housing'] as $value) {
    foreach ($b['RX Housing'] as $value1) {
        foreach ($value as $key => $result) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $value1)) {
                if ($result == $value1[$key]) {
                    $value = array_merge($value, $value1);
                    $c['RX Housing'][] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

    }   
}

var_dump($c);
```

out put is

```
array
  'RX Housing' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'reg_id' => int 63
          'vRegionName' => string 'Boston' (length=6)
          'Forwarded' => int 1
          'Accepted' => int 0
          'Rejected' => int 0
          'Dupe' => int 0
          'PotentialLease' => int 0
          'Lcpc' => int 0
          'CloseLead' => int 0
          'TotalInvamt' => float 0
          'TotalInv' => int 2
      1 => 
        array
          'reg_id' => int 41
          'vRegionName' => string 'Chicago' (length=7)
          'Forwarded' => int 1
          'Accepted' => int 0
          'Rejected' => int 0
          'Dupe' => int 0
          'PotentialLease' => int 0
          'Lcpc' => int 0
          'CloseLead' => int 1
          'TotalInvamt' => float 954
          'TotalInv' => int 8
```